# Decrypt with PUBLIC key pycrypto RSA python

Tags: python-2.7, encryption, rsa, public-key, pycrypto

Using the RSA module in the pycrypto module how can you decrypt with the **PUBLIC** KEY. Any peice of code where a public key is imported and decrypts a string will work.

Answers to this question posted previously give code to decrypt with the private key or verify a message encrypted with the private key. That is not what I'm doing here. I want the program to DECRYPT with the **PUBLIC** key and only the **PUBLIC** key without a private key.

If this is impossible with pycrypto or pycrypto is deprecated or insecure, is there any other module that can perform this.

Comment: Why do you need this? If you modify the Pem files you are done.

Comment: Modify pem files? Changing ---Begin Public Key--- to -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- does nothing.

Comment: You need more than that. Swap the `e` and `d`

Comment: Does pycharm have any method to do that or do I need to manually create a method for that.

Comment: AFAIK manually.